# How can I specify an array of objects indexed by a field in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have got this far:

```
testQuestions: { 
   data: [{ adminTestId: number, 
            adminTestQuestionId: number, 
            questionUId: string, 
            subTopidId: number, 
            title: string }] };
```

Now I would like to add in another object called dataMap.  This object is the result of passing the data through a reduce function:

```
 testQuestions.dataMap = data.reduce((rv, v) => {
            rv[v.questionUId] = v;
            return rv;
        }, {});
```

Can someone help by telling me how I can define (inline) dataMap?

```
testQuestions: { 
   data: [{ adminTestId: number, 
            adminTestQuestionId: number, 
            questionUId: string, 
            subTopidId: number, 
            title: string }],
   dataMap: questionUId: string [{ adminTestId: number, 
            adminTestQuestionId: number, 
            questionUId: string, 
            subTopidId: number, 
            title: string }]
```

};

I have tried above but it's not correct. Hope someone can help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close. First lets break out the object type into its own interface for clarity.

```
interface Question {
    adminTestId: number; 
    adminTestQuestionId: number; 
    questionUId: string; 
    subTopidId: number; 
    title: string;
}
```

This is the syntax you were looking for in `dataMap`.

```
interface QuestionMap {
    [QuestionUId: string]: Question;
}
```

All together.

```
interface TestQuestions { 
    data: Question[];
    dataMap: QuestionMap;
}

var testQuestions: TestQuestions = {
    data: [],
    dataMap: {},
};
```